# How do we split a python list at the largest gap, given kth times?

Tags: python, list

Given a list:

`data = [71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51, 86.82, 87.81, 87.87, 146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]`

How do we write a function with two variables: data and k? The data variable would store the list and the k variable would be the amount of lists we want to return.

For example, using the list given above function `separate(data, 2)` should return `[[71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51, 86.82, 87.81, 87.87], [146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]]`

With that being said, `separate(data, 1)` should return this: `[[71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51, 86.82, 87.81, 87.87, 146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]]`

And the `separate(data, 3)` function will return this list: `[[71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51], [86.82, 87.81, 87.87] , [146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]]`

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is your initial list from the question, you can do:

```py
N = 3

gaps = sorted(
    [(i, abs(a - b)) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(data, data[1:]))],
    key=lambda k: -k[1],
)[: N - 1]

out, prev = [], 0
for idx, _ in sorted(gaps):
    out.append(data[prev : idx + 1])
    prev = idx + 1

if prev < len(data):
    out.append(data[prev:])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51], [86.82, 87.81, 87.87], [146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]]
```

---

For `N = 2`:

```py
[[71.4, 72.73, 74.36, 75.38, 76.15, 76.96, 79.51, 86.82, 87.81, 87.87], [146.38, 150.89, 151.16, 152.18, 152.36, 153.27, 155.7, 160.99, 161.36, 164.55]]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Here's the requested function:

```
from itertools import pairwise
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

def separate(data, k=1):
    gaps = (q - p for p, q in pairwise(data))
    biggest = nlargest(k-1, enumerate(gaps, 1), key=itemgetter(1))
    slice_points = [0] + sorted(map(itemgetter(0), biggest)) + [None]
    return [data[i : j] for i, j in pairwise(slice_points)]
```

### How it works

The [pairwise()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) function groups the data in pairs:

```
[(71.4, 72.73), (72.73, 74.36), (74.36, 75.38), ...]
```

The [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) subtracts each pair giving the gap between them:

```
[1.3299999999999983, 1.6299999999999955, 1.019999999999996, ...]
```

The [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function tracks the slice point for each of the gaps::

[(1, 1.3299999999999983),
(2, 1.6299999999999955),
(3, 1.019999999999996),
...
]

The [itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function extracts the gap of the position/gap_size tuple:

```
>>> t = (1, 1.3299999999999983)
>>> itemgetter(1)(t)
1.3299999999999983
```

The [nlargest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) functions extracts the biggest gaps and their corresponding slice points:

```
[(10, 58.50999999999999), (7, 7.309999999999988)]
```

We use `itemgetter(0)` to extract the slice points and run [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to put them in the same order they appear in the dataset:

```
[7, 10]
```

Next, `0` is prepended because the first slice starts at zero.  A `None` is appended because the last slice goes to the end of the dataset.

```
[0, 7, 10, None]
```

We run `pairwise()` again to group the slice points:

```
[(0, 7), (7, 10), (10, None)]
```

Lastly, the slices are applied to the dataset, giving the desired result:

```
[data[i : j] for i, j in pairwise(slice_points)]
```

Comment: `large_gaps = largest(k, gaps)` should probably be `large_gaps = nlargest(k-1, gaps)` instead, since splitting the list into `k` sublists requires `k-1` splits.

Comment: itertools does not have a function pairwise(). the import should be:  'from more_itertools import pairwise'

Comment: @Iroth The `pairwise()` function became part of itertools in Python 3.10. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise